# Understanding work_queue & create_thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, ppl

Understanding the difference between a work_queue or create_thread. My understanding of a work_queue is it executes threads on a kernel which work asynchronously with one another because these have the ability to sleep and be scheduled. My understanding of a create_thread is that is that at execution time is assigned a single job and only that job and executes through the OS.

Reason for question:
So we're working with parallel_for's in my parallel processing class but Im a little confused. So the p_f uses the work_queue over the create_thread but Im not sure I understand why. Create_thread will create n threads (specified by the function) in order to do something where as the work-queue creates threads based on how many cpu's are available. Is this the reason why the p_f uses the work_queue rather than the create threads? Appreciate the help!

Comment: More information, such as a link to the `parallel_for` you are working with would help people answer this question. For example, are you using [this `parallel_for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470426.aspx#parallel_for)?

Comment: Its more of a question that was presented to me on how the parallel_for function works. However I'm not really finding much information on that it uses a work_queue specifically... the only explanation I can really find is from msdn's website, but it doesnt mention that it uses this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470426.aspx#parallel_for

Comment: The question Ive been presented with is why does it use the work_queue over using a create_thread. The only thing I can think of is because the parallel_for runs (using msdn as guide) it uses kernal threads in order to partition work among threads..and I think because the kernal threads (using the work_queue) these have the capability to sleep and be scheduled with which helps it divide the work up where the create_thread is created at that time and needs to immediately..if that makes sense

Comment: You probably won't find *anything* on it using a "work_queue" over using "create_thread" because that's an implementation detail. Note that the articles we link don't specify *how* `parallel_for` is implemented. This allows flexibility, for example if the compiler decides to place a `parallel_for` on a single core it does better *not* to spawn threads, but just to implement it as a `for`-loop. Asking about implementation details is thin-ice at best, as it may change between updates or even between systems.

Comment: What the person asking you the question is angling at is: "Do you know the difference between 'create_thread' and 'work_queue'?" Which brings me to a very important question, namely: "Do you know the difference between 'create_thread' and 'work_queue'?" If not then please update this question or create a new one asking the actual question here.

Comment: The difference between a create_thread and work_queue is that a create_thread is meant to one thing and only that one thing assigned to it at that time and is executed in the OS. Where the work_queue is executed through threads in the kernel and these threads can sleep when they are say attempting to change something already locked by another thread and they can be scheduled.

Comment: So again...Im guessing the reason you would use a work_queue with a parallel_for function would be because of the ability to sleep and schedule while say the function executes another half of the program. Unless my understanding of the w_q and c_t are wrong...?

Comment: As far as the rationale behind which one of these is used to implement `parallel_for`, I'm sure that Microsoft picked the one that performed best for the targeted system/compiler. The question that needs to be asked is: "Unless my understanding of the "w_q" and "c_t" are wrong...?" Please change the question to that or open a new one.

Comment: I have changed the question. Saying that " I'm sure that Microsoft picked the one that performed best for the targeted system/compiler" doesn't really answer the question I originally posed. The direction I am looking for would be a reason the parallel_for function would use the work_queue over create_thread is because....where again based on my understand of the two..would be as I stated above. So now my question is changed....is my understanding of how each of the 2 work....correct? Or am I missing something...